# Adding MongoDB as an external datasource in WSO2

Tags: mongodb, wso2, datasource, wso2-esb

I want to add MongoDB as an external datasource in WSO2 EI 6.4.0. In admin console, there is no MongoDB option in datasource list.

[image: WSO2 EI new datasource]
Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Datasources, it only supports RDBMS databases. As MongoDB is not an RDBMS database it is not supported by default.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to integrate MongoDB with a connector or with adding mongo.jar to WSO2 EI?

Comment: You can write a custom datasource for MongoDB.

Comment: Hi, could you share the configuration details?